# Windows Socket: using ws2_32.dll can't connect

Tags: sockets, tcp

a socket client, that imports the ws2_32 to connect to a waiting (localhost) SocketServer:

```
 conn_socket = socket(AF_INET, socket_type, 0); // ok conn_socket = 1132
 Print("Client: Client connecting to: "+ server_addr+" => "+(string)conn_socket,
           " AddrLen: ",(string)(ArraySize(server)<<2));
 Print("serv[]: ",(string)server[0]," ",(string)server[1]," ",(string)server[2]," ",
          (string)server[3]," ",(string)server[4]);
 retval=connect(conn_socket, server, ArraySize(server)<<2); // this fails
```

this prints out:

```
 Client: Client connecting to: 127.0.0.1 => 1872 AddrLen: 20
 serv[]: -687407102 0 0 0 0
```

with Error:

```
 Error 10049 means: WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL Cannot assign requested address.
```

Could it be that I do have Win 7.64 but this function works only correct on 32-Bit?

```
  // addr[0] = 0
  // port = 2007
  int2arr(server,sin_addr,addr[0]);
  int2arr(server,sin_family,AF_INET);
  int2arr(server,sin_port,htons(port));

void int2arr(int& arr[], int field, int value) {
    if (field<0) field=-field;
    int l=field>>16;
    if (l==0) return; //(0);
    if (l>4) l=4;
    field&=0xFFFF;
    int p=field>>2;
    int o=field%4;
    value&=0xFFFFFFFF>>((4-l)<<3);
    arr[p]&=0xFFFFFFFF>>((4-o)<<3);
    arr[p]|=value<<(o<<3);
    if (o+l>4){
        p++;
        arr[p]&=0xFFFFFFFF<<((o+l-4)<<3);
        arr[p]|=value>>((8-o-l)<<3);
    }
}
int htons(int s) {
    if (WS_BIGENDIAN!=0) return(s);
    return(((s&0xFF)<<8) | ((s&0xFF00)>>8));
}
```

What do I have to do in this case?
How should look like the server[0] entry? Actually is has -687407102
and should connect to a SocketServer at localhost (120.0.0.1) at port 2007?

Comment: Use an address that is available. Speculating about unlikely 32/64-bit differences isn't useful. What makes you think the result of shifting something left by 2 is going to yield a usable IP address?

Comment: It's a published code and therefore it should work at least it should have worked and it works as it opens a Socket it only cannot connect.